# Yii, file upload using CMultiFileUpload

Tags: php, yii

I'm total newbie in Yii so dont get mad. I cant figure out how CUploadFile works. I have my view file:

```
<div class="form form-custom">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'image-temp-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'car_type'); ?>
        <?php
        $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'attribute'=>'car_type',
            //'name' => 'files',
            'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png',
            'denied'=>'File is not allowed',
            'max'=>3,
        ));
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'car_type'); ?>
    </div>



    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

My controller broken down to bits:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new EeCarTypes;

    if ( isset( $_FILES['EeCarTypes']))
    {
        $images = $_FILES['EeCarTypes'];
       $model->car_type = $images['name']['car_type'][0];
        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'car_type');
        CVarDumper::Dump($uploadedFile, 10 ,true);
        $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/upload/cartypes/'.'hehehe');
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

and my model:

public $car_type;

```
public function rules()
    {
            // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
            // will receive user inputs.
            return array(
     //   array('image', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
                    array('car_type', 'length', 'max'=>255),
                    // The following rule is used by search().
                    // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
                    array('id, car_type', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            );
    }
```

Everting goes smooth until I try to upload in controller. Everything I put as arguments in CUploadedFile::getInstance(); results in NULL;

Comment: try adding this line in your model rules   array('image', 'car_type','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true),

Answer (score 0):

The file variable must be given a rule that forces it of type file.

```
    array('car_type', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png')
```

References
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/